# How to get germs off of paper?

Tags: paper, safety

I made a little drawing which I accidentally dropped on a floor which must have been loaded with tons of bacteria. To make matters even worse, I had a hard time picking it up, so it must have been on the dirty floor for a good 30 seconds or so.

Anyways, I was wondering if it would be possible to disinfect my paper drawing so that I can kiss it without worrying about getting sick. (It's a drawing of the Blessed Virgin Mary, so I often kiss her feet in veneration.) Of course, washing the image with soap and water is out of the question, as that would basically destroy it.

One thought I had was to heat up the paper image to kill the germs, but how would I do that? Is it possible to do that without destroying/deforming the image?

I hope I'm on the right .SE site to ask this question. (If not, please tell me where to go.)

Comment: This presumes that whatever germs you think are on the floor: a) actually transferred to the piece b) can actually _survive_ on the piece c) aren't worse than the germs already on your hands and mouth.

Comment: As far as on-topicness, I'm not sure if this stack is the right fit, but I'm not sure it _isn't_. I can see similar questions coming up about disinfecting pieces, and we've had some related ones in the past.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about arts and crafts per se. The same question could apply to anything dropped on the floor. Perhaps it belongs in https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I've gone with the community votes here and cast the final close vote. Medical Science may or may not be the right place. If you want to appeal the on-topicness for _this_ site, you can ask a question on [meta] regarding it. Best of luck.

Comment: Dag nabbit... Should have waited to close. I think Henry provided a really good answer!

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet would be to laminate the picture at a local print shop.  That would seal whatever has gotten onto the paper behind an impermeable barrier of clean plastic.

Barring that, you can probably get rid of most of the bacteria by exposing your drawing to ultraviolet light.  UV light is used in many industries as a disinfectant.

As for the amount of time that your picture spent on the floor, according to [MythBusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODfbaZ9_XzQ), time isn't as important as it appears.

Comment: Just as a gentle caution: laminating a piece, especially one that isn't sealed, can cause damage (as the laminate can sometimes pull up parts of the artwork, especially if it ever has to be removed and re-laminated). UV might also work, but as a general solution to disinfecting art, UV is not friendly towards paper or colors. Depending on the exact piece of art, there may be additional steps required.

Comment: @WebHead - sounds like archival issues are not the prime concern here... pretty sure repeated kissing of an image can cause damage as well.  The lamination may actually prolong its life.

Comment: @rebusB Perhaps, but in general answers should be heplful for everyone with th4 same or similar root question, even if the reason for asking is different.

Comment: @WebHead - Exactly... the question is not about archiving a drawing, it is about making it safe for a utilitarian purpose and the answer seems totally reasonable. I voted to reopen.

Comment: @rebusB I think this probably needs a [meta] question, unless you think enough reopen votes will happen. I'm not sure one way or another, so I would prefer to go to with the community's decision, only casting a final vote instead of an overruling one.

Comment: @WebHead - thats cool. It has four upvotes, maybe voters will comeback to vote to reopen though I doubt it. Its just a (no offense to OP) unusual question, at first it seemed off topic (germs!?) but then it does fit in that it is trying to address a specific problem in the production of an artwork (I guess this is getting meta again... will think on that.)